# Connection aborted error when trying to run docker-compose up with podman

Tags: docker-compose, podman

When trying to run docker-compose with podman as root-less user the following error comes up .

Start Podman with Rootless mode and compose container with docker-compose.
--> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied (File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 677, in urlopen)

```
[----@-------- unittesting]$ docker-compose up -d                                                                                                                                                                                            Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 677, in urlopen
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 392, in _make_request
  File "http/client.py", line 1277, in request
  File "http/client.py", line 1323, in _send_request
  File "http/client.py", line 1272, in endheaders
  File "http/client.py", line 1032, in _send_output
  File "http/client.py", line 972, in send
  File "docker/transport/unixconn.py", line 43, in connect
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 727, in urlopen
  File "urllib3/util/retry.py", line 410, in increment
  File "urllib3/packages/six.py", line 734, in reraise
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 677, in urlopen
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 392, in _make_request
  File "http/client.py", line 1277, in request
  File "http/client.py", line 1323, in _send_request
  File "http/client.py", line 1272, in endheaders
  File "http/client.py", line 1032, in _send_output
  File "http/client.py", line 972, in send
  File "docker/transport/unixconn.py", line 43, in connect
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', PermissionError(13, 'P                                                                                                                                                                             ermission denied'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "docker/api/client.py", line 214, in _retrieve_server_version
  File "docker/api/daemon.py", line 181, in version
  File "docker/utils/decorators.py", line 46, in inner
  File "docker/api/client.py", line 237, in _get
  File "requests/sessions.py", line 543, in get
  File "requests/sessions.py", line 530, in request
  File "requests/sessions.py", line 643, in send
  File "requests/adapters.py", line 498, in send
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', PermissionError(13,                                                                                                                                                                              'Permission denied'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "docker-compose", line 3, in <module>
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 81, in main
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 200, in perform_command
  File "compose/cli/command.py", line 70, in project_from_options
  File "compose/cli/command.py", line 153, in get_project
  File "compose/cli/docker_client.py", line 43, in get_client
  File "compose/cli/docker_client.py", line 170, in docker_client
  File "docker/api/client.py", line 197, in __init__
  File "docker/api/client.py", line 222, in _retrieve_server_version
docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API version: ('Connec                                                                                                                                                                             tion aborted.', PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied'))
[3903338] Failed to execute script docker-compose

[----@---- unittesting]$ sudo systemctl list-unit-files | grep podman
Password:
podman-auto-update.service                 disabled
podman-restart.service                     disabled
podman.service                             disabled
podman.socket                              enabled
podman-auto-update.timer                   disabled
```

I've redefined the DOCKER_HOST variable as suggested in (https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/13468).

Comment: What exactly is the value of `DOCKER_HOST` in your environment? Please put enough information in your question for us to reproduce the problem you're asking about.